# How to find the max number from a given array of numbers?

Tags: javascript

How in javaScript from this array find the maximum number

```
[ [ 'a' , 0.01 ] , [ 'b' , 0.02 ] , ...]
```

I need to find the maximum number of 0.01 , 0.02 ...

How in javaScript from the above array

make this array

```
 [ 0.01 , 0.02 , ...]
```

and using the function Math.max() find the maximum number?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: `map()`, then `Math.max()`

Comment: try `Math.max(...array.map(([_, n]) => n))`

Comment: You always have 2 values in the sub arrays and the second one is always a number?

Comment: [Many more dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+math.max+array+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the value by destructuring the key-value pair and returning the value. After you get the values, you can spread them in the `Math.max` call.

```js
const arr = [ [ 'a' , 0.01 ] , [ 'b' , 0.02 ] ];

console.log(Math.max(...arr.map(([k, v]) => v)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
array = [['a' , 0.01] , ['b' , 0.02] , ...]
    
const numberArray = array.map(([key, value]) => value)
```

And then use the `Math.max()` method.